# How to run cron job before midnight to after midnight (over midnight)?

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

How can I create a cron job that runs from 19:00 to 5:00?  This doesn't work:

```
* 19-05 * * ....
```

Should I use two jobs?

```
    * 19-23 * * .... 
    *  1-5  * * ....
```

Comment: That's interesting!  I haven't made this experiment, but I'm leaning towards 2 lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On some distributions you can:

```
* 19-23,0-5 * * *
```

Check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67158/crontab-entry-with-hour-range-going-over-midnight

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that 19-23,0-5 works on Ubuntu server 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to lines:

```
* 19-23 * * .... 
* 0-05 * * ....
```

Comment: It's a script that I wanna run every minute of this period of time.

Comment: @Farhadix - ok, so I miss read your question. you should probably edit and make it clearer. Edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will end up to split it up, like this:

```
*/10 22-23 * * * logger "brooks was here"
*/10 00-05 * * * logger "brooks was here after midnight"
```